# Dynamic subset a dataframe after a pattern colname in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

**Input (df)**

```
> df
  gender age LIST_12 LIST_24 LIST_42 anxious happy nervous
1     11  12      20      18      29      31     6      28
2     35  25      26      23       9      34    13      21
3     20   8      28      27      26      26    34      29
4     24  35      10      11      18      25    26       3
5     34   8       4       3      29      33    25      35
```

**Desired output (dfSubset)**

What would be the best way to get a subset containing only columns after LIST_ to the end. In this case I would like to subset only : anxious, happy and nervous column.

```
  anxious happy nervous
1      31     6      28
2      34    13      21
3      26    34      29
4      25    26       3
5      33    25      35
```

**Infos**

I know that I can run the following code in order to subset only the column-names beginning with the word LIST_. But it's not what I am looking for...

```
dfSubset = subset(x = df, select =  grep("LIST_", names(df)))
dfSubset
```

**Reproducible source**

```
df <- structure(list(gender = c(11L, 35L, 20L, 24L, 34L), age = c(12L, 
25L, 8L, 35L, 8L), LIST_12 = c(20L, 26L, 28L, 10L, 4L), LIST_24 = c(18L, 
23L, 27L, 11L, 3L), LIST_42 = c(29L, 9L, 26L, 18L, 29L), anxious = c(31L, 
34L, 26L, 25L, 33L), happy = c(6L, 13L, 34L, 26L, 25L), nervous = c(28L, 
21L, 29L, 3L, 35L)), .Names = c("gender", "age", "LIST_12", "LIST_24", 
"LIST_42", "anxious", "happy", "nervous"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks Richard it works. I think it can be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find which column is the last one beginning with `LIST`, add 1, and use that number to begin a sequence to the number of columns.

```
df[(max(grep("^LIST", names(df))) + 1):ncol(df)]
#   anxious happy nervous
# 1      31     6      28
# 2      34    13      21
# 3      26    34      29
# 4      25    26       3
# 5      33    25      35
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(-matches("LIST|gender|age"))
#    anxious happy nervous
#1      31     6      28
#2      34    13      21
#3      26    34      29
#4      25    26       3
#5      33    25      35
```

---

Or it could be

```
df %>% 
     select((tail(matches("LIST"),1)+1):ncol(.))
```

Comment: I think it s not columns "after a pattern", its columns besides patterns